# iPhone:From Camera user can only take 'portrait' oriented photos

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera

In my app image is fatched from camera and when taking a photo, if someone moves the camera horizontal it takes a horizontal picture that is then streched out. Is there a way to 
stop the camera from moving into horizontal mode? The user can only take 
'portrait' oriented photos.

Is there any way to put this kind of functionality?

thanx in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to check if the width is bigger than the height of the picture taken (landscape picture), and if that is the case, show an alert to the users to explain that just portrait pictures are supported.

It would be something like this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

if (image.size.width > image.size.height) {
    // Landscape
} else {
    // Portrait
}}
```